# Conda unexpected token error

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda

When I try to run conda or activate i get the following error:

```
~]$ conda

env/bin/conda: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `conda.cli.main'
env/bin/conda: line 6: `    sys.exit(conda.cli.main())'
```

The contents of my conda file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import conda.cli

    sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
```

Any ideas?

update:
The path is not the problem if i remove it and specify the python executable on the command line it still gives the same error.

Comment: Why did you replace the shebang line with `#!/bin/bash`?  This is a Python script.

Comment: Maybe it's not you, but some bug in anaconda.  In any case, this is weird.

Comment: #!/bin/bash might be the problem, but when I make it point to anaconda/bin/python and run conda it gets changed to #!/opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/bin/python.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Conda provides its own `conda` binary. If you don't want to specify absolute path each time you run it, just add directory to `$PATH` and let shell pick it up for you. Please update your question instead of only answering by comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparantly another user corrupted our copy of anaconda, he reinstalled it and now my enviorment functions as expected.

Thanks for the feedback.